# Is good pratice create a project maven module specific for tests?

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, ant, multi-module

I have a ANT project and I'm migrating to maven. This project has some src folders and for each src folder I decided to create a maven module project.

The problem is that each src folder has unit tests and at build all classes are compiled in a classes folder, so all the dependences between tests are resolved.

Creating maven modules, one module do not recognize the dependencies between modules.

I thought about creating a maven project specific for tests. Is this a good pratice or there is another way?

Comment: unit tests shold belong to one module, so it should be in the same modulke unter `src/test`

Comment: The actual problem and resolution for this is quite clear. The OP is simply asking the wrong question in the title. The solution put forward by @question_maven_com is technically correct but they could probably elaborate some more for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, a Maven project has a src/main and a src/test folder, and you put the unit tests for the project into the src/test folder.

If your tests need additional dependencies, you can declare them with test scope in your pom.

Comment: The problem is, I have this structure:

-- PARENT
----- module1
----- module2
----- module3

module2 has classes that depends of another classes from module1 that are included in src/test folder.

in pom.xml of module2 I have module1 as dependecy. But do not recognize the src/test classes of module 1.

Do you know why?

Comment: This is probably an unfortunate construction. In this case I would recommend to have a test-util module that gathers helper classes for tests. Nothing should depend on src/test folders. The tests itself should remain in the src/test folders.

Comment: yes , I will have to do it. thx for help

Answer (score 0):

```
parent_test
    -> module1_test
    -> module2_test
    -> module3_test
```

1. Use test-jar https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html
2. Example in module2_test

   ```
       <dependency>
           <groupId>groupId</groupId>
           <artifactId>module1_test</artifactId>
           <type>test-jar</type>
           <version>version</version>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
   ```